# undefined symbol with lib created with jni and OpenCV

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I don't understand how can I create a native method which take a Mat and return it modified.

I have this code in java class:

```
private native void getCanny(long mat);
getCanny(mat.getNativeObjAddr());
```

and the Mat2Image.h generated:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Mat2Image */

#ifndef _Included_Mat2Image
#define _Included_Mat2Image
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Mat2Image
 * Method:    getCanny
 * Signature: (J)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Mat2Image_getCanny
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and this is the .cpp I've made:

```
#include "Mat2Image.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Mat2Image_getCanny
   (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jlong matr){


       cv::Mat* frame=(cv::Mat*)matr;
            cv::cvtColor(*frame, *frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cv::GaussianBlur(*frame, *frame, cv::Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
            cv::Canny(*frame, *frame, 0, 30, 3);


}
```

but when I try to run the method I have this error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/buzzo/Downloads/helloJni-master/jni/libMat.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8cvtColorERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEii
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the above?

Comment: the .cpp code doesn't work, i don't understand how to made it

Comment: Well, I sorta guessed that the .cpp code didn't work, just judging by the fact that this question is here in the first place.  But we need more details.  What do you expect it to do?  Why do you expect it to do this?  What is it actually doing?  Without these details, we cannot help you.

Comment: I just asking how to create a native method to take a Mat and return a Mat in c++ and use it in java

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a `.so` you usually don't link dependendent libraries with it. You add them when building the executable instead. And the linker doesn't complain about missing symbols when building the `.so`, but will do so when you build the executable.

For JNI however, this doesn't work becase you use the `java` executable, which is fixed, and you load your library dynamically. So you have to link the dependendent library into your `.so`. Find out what library `cvtColor` and the other functions are in and look up the linker options for your toolchain to see how you need to specify it on the command line. Also be aware that with most  linkers the order of arguments matters.

Comment: Ok, forget that. I just saw that you found out yourself, when I noticed your other questions